# Error 3090003 when calling a contract from another contract

Tags: smart-contract, permissions

I have deployed contracts hello and callhello, where callhello makes a call to hello, which in turn prints an output. However, i'm not getting the result I'm hoping for

```
cleos push action callhello callhi '["callhello", "hi"]' -p callhello@active
Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"callhello","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms
```

This is the call from callhello to hello

```
        action(
                permission_level{ user, N(active) },
                N(hello), N(hi),
                std::make_tuple(user, _self)
                ).send();
```

Also, this is the permissions for the account hello:

```
 cleos get account hello
 privileged: false
 permissions: 
 owner     1:    1 EOS5eynjBhk33eGpxFHvAbPXYXqHRhPJYHsQmpQptqdeVLJPpi6aN
    active     1:    1 EOS6aV6kN65XBWpD7h7BHP51kfJceKNSnGGdhT9WpD7Nw1vcyXEys1 callhello@active, 
       subperm     1:    1 callhello@active, 1 hello@active,
```

So I thought that callhello would be able to push the action. I'm thinking that the signature isn't linked from one contract to the next, but don't know how to do that if so. Thankful for any help

Comment: you declared callhello@active to do the hello action, but your privilege is callhello@eosio.code, which does not satisfy your declared auth

Answer (score 2):

As [Jimmy](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/error-3090003-when-calling-a-contract-from-another-contract#comment1024_1234) mentioned contract `callhello` needs permission `eosio.code`.

To solve that you can run the `cleos set account permission` command:

```
cleos set account permission callhello active \
'{"threshold": 1,
  "keys": [{
    "key": "'${EOS_KEY}'",
    "weight": 1
  }],
  "accounts": [{
    "permission": {"actor": "callhello",
               "permission": "eosio.code"},
               "weight": 1
  }]}' owner -p callhello
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason this can happen is if you didn't import your active key into your cleos wallet. Remember that signing keys from your wallet is done completely separate from the contract.

To check if your key is there

```
cleos wallet unlock --password PW************
cleos wallet keys
```

Then to import your key

```
cleos wallet import 5XYZ***********
```